# error: you need to load the kernel first

Tags: boot, updates, data-recovery, error-handling, interrupts

Last night, I jumped to update my Ubuntu, I left it overnight and when I woke up there was a strange screen, I turned it off and turned it on again, right now I get this error on the screen

```
error: failure reading sector ex74706dae from hde".
error: failure reading sector 0x74706d00 from "hde" 
error: failure reading sector exe from 'hde".
error: failure reading sector 0x74706da0 from "hde
error: failure reading sector 0x74706d00 from "hde" 
error: failure reading sector exe from 'hde'.
error: no such device: 26e763a0-050d-464f-a8c5-1cc77a10cae9.
Loading Linux 5.15.0-46-generic ...
error: disk hde, gpt5' not found.
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: you need to load the kernel first.
Press any key to continue....
```

I don't know how serious the error is, at least I would like to recover my personal data

Comment: You've provided no product/release details, though at this stage I'd not suggest trying to boot/use your existing system, instead working out the health of the drive & planning how to recovery any data you don't have safely backed up, ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools using your drive's SMART capability from *live* media.

Comment: Upgrade from which release to which release? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: My initial version is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the one I was updating to was the latest version Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (if I'm not mistaken), the update window just appeared, and I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem, I simply installed ubuntu on my disk partition, and it let me access all the files on the other partition that was corrupted